# How to map dirty strings to numbers, in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a python project and I'm working with data from a csv file and I'm trying to convert user data into something usable by converting data from strings to float values.
Here is one such relevant column of data

```
F10
White
White
Black
Asian-Pac-Islander
White
Black
...
```

This is the code I'm using;

```
trainData = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
trainData['F10'].map({' White': 0, ' Black': 1, ' Asian-Pac-Islander': 2, 'white': 0, 'White': 0, 'Black': 1, 'Asian-Pac-Islander': 2,  " White": 0, " Black": 1, " Asian-Pac-Islander": 2, "white": 0, "White": 0, "Black": 1, "Asian-Pac-Islander": 2})
```

Unfortunately, despite this, when I print out trainData, the strings Asian-Pac-Islander, White, Black, all still appear. [I've been using this as a guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's always best to work with lowercase values, so you don't have to match all variations. This can be achieved with `str.lower()`.
- Use `str.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
trainData = pd.DataFrame({'F10': ['White ', 'White', 'Black', ' Asian-Pac-Islander', ' White ', ' Black']})

# strip, lower and map
trainData['F10_numeric'] = trainData['F10'].str.strip().str.lower().map({'white': 0, 'black': 1, 'asian-pac-islander': 2})

# display(trainData)
                   F10  F10_numeric
0               White             0
1                White            0
2                Black            1
3   Asian-Pac-Islander            2
4               White             0
5                Black            1
```

- The previous code doesn't fix the `F10` column, it only adjusts it for the mapping.
- The following, will update `F10`, and then map the values to numbers.

```py
# fix F10
trainData['F10'] = trainData['F10'].str.strip().str.lower()

# map on the fixed F10 column
trainData['F10_numeric'] = trainData['F10'].map({'white': 0, 'black': 1, 'asian-pac-islander': 2})

# display(trainData)
                  F10  F10_numeric
0               white            0
1               white            0
2               black            1
3  asian-pac-islander            2
4               white            0
5               black            1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the actual column in the dataframe you have to use this:

```
trainData['F10'].replace({' White': 0, ' Black': 1, ' Asian-Pac-Islander': 2, 'white': 0, 'White': 0, 'Black': 1, 'Asian-Pac-Islander': 2,  " White": 0, " Black": 1, " Asian-Pac-Islander": 2, "white": 0, "White": 0, "Black": 1, "Asian-Pac-Islander": 2}, inplace=True)
```

note that I used `inplace=True`

A better alternative which doesn't require `inplace=True` would be this:

```
trainData['F10'] = trainData['F10'].str.strip().str.lower().replace({'white': 0, 'black': 1, 'asian-pac-islander': 2})
```